How to implement Service Discovery with Kong?
Currently we are using Eureka for Service discovery with Spring boot apps. We would like to implement Kong API Gateway as API Gateway layer. As far as I have read, Kong cannot be integrated with Eureka.
Kong documentation suggests below,
Kong acts as the service registry, keeping a record of the available target instances for the upstream services. When a target comes online, it must register itself with Kong by sending a request to the Admin API.
How to set up Kong to act as Service registry and how to enable the set up in the underlying Spring boot apps to register itself to Kong considering Kong acts as a Service registry.
Can we use Kubernetes CoreDNS for Service discovery ? If so, how do we set it up in Kong ?
How do we create the Upstream with target ? Would the Kubernetes Service name become a target in Kong Gateway ?
